# Creating individual sorting at runtime with shopware 6

Tags: sorting, symfony, shopware6

**Problem**:

I am trying to create a sorting without using the **Database Migration**. I tried doing it as described in the
[**Documentation**](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-sorting-product-listing.html#create-individual-sorting-at-runtime) but I get the error: `The "custom-sorting" couldn't be found`. I also tried using the `AbstractListingProcessor` instead of the **Event Subscriber** but it didn't work as well.

**Solution (but at the same time not really the solution that I want):**

I am able to make it work when using the following [**Database Migration Documentation**](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-sorting-product-listing.html#create-individual-sorting-with-migration) but as it says in the Documentation I can either use the **Event** **Subscriber** or the **Database Migration** and I would like to use the **Event Subscriber**/`AbstractListingProcessor` if possible.

**Here is a snippet of my code:**

```
  class CustomSortingProcessor extends AbstractListingProcessor
 {
      public function getDecorated() : AbstractListingProcessor
      {
          throw new DecorationPatternException(self::class);
      }

public function prepare(Request $request, Criteria $criteria, SalesChannelContext 
    $context): void

    /** @var ProductSortingCollection $availableSortings */
    $availableSorting = $criteria->getExtension('sortings') ?? new 
     ProductSortingCollection();

    $customSortingProcessorEntity = new ProductSortingEntity();
    $customSortingProcessorEntity->setId(Uuid::randomHex());
    $customSortingProcessorEntity->setActive(true);
    $customSortingProcessorEntity->setTranslated(['label' => 'Custom Sorting']);
    $customSortingProcessorEntity->setKey('custom-sorting');
    $customSortingProcessorEntity->setPriority(5);
    $customSortingProcessorEntity->setFields([
        [
            'field' => 'deepLearning.sold',
            'order' => 'desc',
            'priority' => 1,
            'naturalSorting' => 0,
        ],
    ]);

    $availableSorting->add($customSortingProcessorEntity);

    $criteria->addExtension('sortings', $availableSorting);
        }
      }
```